# “Inspect.exe” can't find some elements on a different machine, why?

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, ui-testing, pywinauto

Inspect.exe is behaving differently on different machines my development pc can see all the automationIds I expose in my application. But on our testers PC Inspect cant find these automationIds. Both PC are using the same windows sdk inspect application. I saw this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522454/inspect-exe-cant-find-some-elements-on-my-laptop-why) describing how QT runtime could be a cause.
But there is no description of how the QT runtime issue was resolved between the 2 pcs.

Comment: What is `inspect.exe`?

Comment: What does QT have to do with C# and what is `inspect.exe`? What you call automation IDs are most likely the *Class IDs* and *Prog IDs* of COM and automation objects. You can find them in the registry. They aren't related to UI or testing.

Comment: I looking for help with UI automation using PyWinAuto to test WPF applications UI. Inspect.exe is part of the windows 10 SDK, AutomationIds are an attached properties used to label controls. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties.automationid

Comment: @RedX @Panagiotis Kanavos guys `Inspect.exe` is GUI inspector tool from Windows SDK. Tags "ui-automation" and "wpf" assume you know what it is.

Comment: @user3094988 maybe it's worth taking a look at how you build your app. The tag is "WPF" so the app doesn't contain any Qt element inside, right? Please describe the app structure in more details. Screenshots from `Inspect.exe` would be helpful.

Comment: It might be different versions of .NET Framework since it's probably not a Qt.

Comment: I have added a AutomationIds to a syncfusion datagrid <code> xmlns:sf="schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf" <Grid> <sf:SfDataGrid AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_DataGrid" x:Name="DataGrid" AllowEditing="True" AllowDeleting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateRelations="False" EditTrigger="OnTap" AddNewRowPosition="Bottom"............. </code>